# Customize ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to customize my android actionbar, i have read this [link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html) and i interested in this effect (you can see that in this [video link](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animation-responsive-interation-radialReact-example_large_xhdpi.webm)), here an example of the sequence:

[image]

Thanks, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/balysv/material-menu

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide your action bar and create your oun custom action bar and `include` that action bar in all layouts.

To hide action bar `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` use this code before before **setContentView**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  // This code will hide Action Bar form your UI
setContentView(R.layout.mailActivity);
```

Now create your own custom action bar **custom_actionbar.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="#CAEFEE"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    android:contentDescription="@string/home"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/home" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titletext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/settings"
    android:src="@drawable/settings"
    android:text="@string/settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here you mention the height of your custom action bar. Now add this into your UI like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e5fafb" >

<include layout="@layout/custom_actionbar"/>  // This code will add your custom Action  bar into Layout

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/textview1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'am interest in a icon "change effect",sorry I do not know how to say, please see the video link, the icon that is in the left, another interesting thing is that the icon is on actionbar. Do you know how do something like this?